# Редактируемая таблица heavyTable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

использую heavytable.js для создания редактируемой таблицы, все работает, но если я по нажатию на кнопку добавляю новую строку, то при клике на ячейку она не доступна, пока не обновишь страницы

```js
$(".nav_data .add_btn").click(function() {
  $("table.heavyTable tbody").append('<tr data-id="" data-new="1"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>')
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.heavyTable = function(params) {

    params = $.extend( {
      startPosition: {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
      }
    }, params);

    this.each(function() {
      var 
        $hTable = $(this).find('tbody'),
        i = 0,
        x = params.startPosition.x,
        y = params.startPosition.y,
        max = {
          y: $hTable.find('tr').length,
          x: $hTable.parent().find('th').length
        };
        
      //console.log(xMax + '*' + yMax);
      
      function clearCell () {    
        content = $hTable.find('.selected input').val();
        $hTable.find('.selected').html(content);
        $hTable.find('.selected').toggleClass('selected');
      }

      function selectCell () {
        if ( y > max.y ) y = max.y;
        if ( x > max.x ) x = max.x;
        if ( y < 1 ) y = 1;
        if ( x < 1 ) x = 1;
        currentCell = 
         $hTable
            .find('tr:nth-child('+(y)+')')
            .find('td:nth-child('+(x)+')');
        content = currentCell.html();
        currentCell
          .toggleClass('selected')
        return currentCell;
      }
      
      function edit (currentElement) {
        var input = $('<input>', {type: "text"})
          .val(currentElement.html())
        currentElement.html(input)
        input.focus(); 
      }

      $hTable.find('td').click( function () {
        clearCell();
        x = ($hTable.find('td').index(this) % (max.x) + 1);
        y = ($hTable.find('tr').index($(this).parent()) + 1);
        edit(selectCell());
      });

      $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          clearCell();
          edit(selectCell());
        } else if (e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40  ) {

          clearCell();
          switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37: x--;
            break;
            case 38: y--;
            break;
            case 39: x++;
            break;
            case 40: y++;
            break;
          }
          selectCell();
          return false;
        }
      }); 
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready( function () {
  $('table').heavyTable({
        xPosition: 1,
        yPosition: 1
      }); 
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 320px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #38678f;
}
th {
  background: steelblue;
  height: 54px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #38678f;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #38678f;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px #568ebd;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}
td:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}
td.selected {
  background: #d7e4ef;
  z-index: ;
}
td input {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
td input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 steelblue;
  color: steelblue;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
}
::selection {
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
}
.heavyTable {
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}
.main {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
.content {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.content p,
.content pre,
.content h2 {
  text-align: left;
}
.content pre {
  padding: 1.2em 0 0.5em;
  background: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  color: #38678f;
}
.content .download {
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  border-radius: 12em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.content .button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #38678f;
  background: steelblue;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 1px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
.content .button:hover {
  background: #4f8aba;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.content .button:active {
  color: #294d6b;
  background: #427aa9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.content .button:focus {
  outline: none;
}


.nav_data{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 48px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e9;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.nav_data .add_btn{
    width: 48px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #99a8c0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 48px;
}
.im-page--history .content_data{
    padding:15px;
}
.search_field {
    height: 48px;
    background: url(assets/img/search-icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    padding-left: 35px;
    color: #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e8ec;
}
.im-page {
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
}
.user_list{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
.user_list li{
    display: flex;
    height: 63px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.user_list li:hover {
    border-top: solid 1px #e7e8ec;
    background-color: #f5f7fa;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e7e8ec;
}
.user_list li:hover .info-block {
    border-color: transparent;
}
.user_list li .info-block{
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: solid 1px #e7e8ec;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.user_list li .info-block span.name  {
    color: #222;
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.im-block{
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 9px 7px 8px 0;
    -moz-force-broken-image-icon: 0;
    background-color: #fafbfc;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.im-page .im-page--dialogs {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 48px 0 45px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.im-page .im-page--history {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.page_block {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7d8db, 0 0 0 1px #e3e4e8;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav_data">
            <button type="button" aria-label="Добавить" data-type="add" class="add_btn"><span class="icon-plus"></span>Добавить</button>
        </div>
<table  class="heavyTable">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Due Date</th>
                        <th>RUB</th>
                        <th>EUR</th>
                        <th>Debit</th>
                        <th>Credit</th>
                        <th>Balanse</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-id="" data-new="0">
                         <td>1</td>
                         <td>2</td>
                         <td>3</td>
                         <td>1</td>
                         <td>2</td>
                         <td>3</td>
                         <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="" data-new="0">
                         <td>1</td>
                         <td>2</td>
                         <td>3</td>
                         <td>1</td>
                         <td>2</td>
                         <td>3</td>
                         <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="" data-new="0">
                         <td>1</td>
                         <td>2</td>
                         <td>3</td>
                         <td>1</td>
                         <td>2</td>
                         <td>3</td>
                         <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="" data-new="1">
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```